# 'Publishing web' page or list?

Tags: publishing-site, publishing-page, content

My contributors need to create content (mainly HTML-style) to be published online.
Should this be stored in a "publishing web" page or in a list (with an HTML column)?

Is it a matter of choosing if the content should be approved or not?

What are the pros and cons?

Answer (score 0):

**Publishing**

If, by online, you mean a publicly accessible web site, that is best served by a publishing site. It's possible to do some limited html publishing through a variety of other tools, but a full fledged .com is best handled with the publishing features.

Publishing features serve the Web Content Management space. Web Content Management in SharePoint, in many cases, can be considered a much different way of using the product than the standard Team Site. The publishing features were derived from a separate product that focused entirely on that purpose.

TechNet has an entire section on how to [Plan web content management in SharePoint Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee476993.aspx) which is targeted at IT Pro's but can be helpful to decision makers such as yourself.

Also, see Andrew Connell's post on [Publishing Field Controls versus Web Parts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ecm/archive/2008/10/09/publishing-sites-field-controls-or-web-parts-that-is-the-question.aspx) and Nik Patel's [Wiki Pages vs Web Part Pages vs Publishing Pages for SharePoint 2010 Intranet Content Pages](http://nikpatel.net/2012/06/08/wiki-pages-vs-web-part-pages-for-sharepoint-intranet-content-pages/).

**List**

On the other hand, if you'd like to use a rich text multi line column type as the HTML column in a list, you should be aware of some restrictions.

For Example

1. [Some html is not allowed](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60281/sharepoint-altering-my-html-and-css) like  `<Script>example</script>`, even with the new SharePoint 2013 embed option.
   [image: screenshot of HTML cannot be inserted dialog]
2. Absolute URLS are converted to relative
   [image]

If you're not going to use publishing features, you should also take a look at alternatives to the Rich Text Multi Line column type

For Example

- [Content Editor Web Part](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/using-the-content-editor-web-part-HA101794745.aspx?CTT=1)
- [Creating Web Pages in SharePoint Designer](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/create-sharepoint-site-pages-HA101782505.aspx)
- [HTML Calculated column](http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/09/01/using-calculated-columns-to-write-html/)